# Если я чищу зубчонки после того, как поем, то это имеет намного больше смысла, чем(,) если я это делаю до этого

Tags: запятые

Запятая эта отнюдь не нужна, так?

> Если я чищу зубчонки после того, как поем, то это имеет намного больше смысла, чем(,) если я это делаю до этого.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запятая, действительно, лишняя:

*Если я чищу зубчонки после того, как поем, то это имеет намного больше смысла, чем если я это делаю до этого*.

Придаточное с *если* переставить нельзя — у него здесь **фиксированная позиция**.

К тому же само сочетание ***чем если*** само по себе кажется **единым союзом**.

Примеры из [Нацкорпуса](https://ruscorpora.ru/results?search=CkgqIQoICAAQChgyIAoQBSAAKPTI%2BNXvyv4IQAVqBDAuOTV4ADICCAE6AQFCHAoaChgKA3JlcRIRCg%2FQp9C10Lwg0LXRgdC70LgwAQ%3D%3D):

> Следовательно, если шкалу прикрепить к узкому колену манометра, то цена деления шкалы его будет в 9 раз большей, **чем если** бы она была прикреплена к широкому колену;

> Да, знаем, и гораздо надежнее, **чем если** бы у нас была книга, в которую мы "вчитывали " бы то, что нам хочется в ней увидеть, как мы постоянно делаем, читая произведения разных писателей: мы видим себя в них и воспринимаем книгу только в меру своего понимания;

> Эта женщина была совершенно правдива; и я уверен, что Христос принял ее слова с гораздо большей готовностью, **чем если** бы она сказала: " Как это прекрасно! " — и пальцем не дотронулась бы до того креста, который надо взять на свои плечи и понести.

И там есть ещë много таких примеров.

---

Вывод: не нужна запятая, придаточное *зафиксировано*.

Comment: Максим, а что такое фиксированная позиция.  Это общепринятый термин?

Comment: @Sharon Фиксированная позиция? Почему общепринятый? Вы и сами использовали эту фразу в ответе на  вопрос о запятой между _поэтому_ и _когда_. Это когда придаточное невозможно переставить в другую часть.

Comment: @Sharon Если осиались какие-то вопросы, а я на них не отвечу, то я сплю. Если вы смотрели мой профиль, знаете, какое у меея время.

Comment: Ладно, спокойной вам ночи...   А мне все кажется, что мы в едином общемосковском ментальном пространстве. Я потом посмотрю, чтобы понять, что вы имели в виду.

Answer (score 1):

Правильно:

*Если я чищу зубы после того, как поем, то это имеет намного **больше** смысла, **чем если** я это делаю до этого.*

Запятая перед союзом ЕСЛИ не нужна. Почему? Здесь придаточное находится **в позиции члена предложения**: *больше смысла в этом, **чем в другом**.*

Другие **примеры:**

*Внизу река кажется темнее и глубже, **чем если** глядеть на нее сверху* (= чем при взгляде на нее сверху). Анаит Григорян. Подводные течения, 2015.

И это лучше, **чем если бы** в ней было что-то ангельское. Аркадий Мацанов. Мастер и подмастерье (2016) .